# richfaces: how to set tooltips's value use javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

has any comments? I dont't want to use format like this :

```
<rich:toolTip followMouse="true" direction="top-right" mode="ajax" value="#{bean.toolTipContent}" horizontalOffset="5" 

    verticalOffset="5" layout="block">

    <f:facet name="defaultContent">

        <f:verbatim>DEFAULT TOOLTIP CONTENT</f:verbatim>

    </f:facet>

</rich:toolTip>
```

for my inputtext did not binding a value in my java bean. can anyone give some advise?

Comment: Someone please help me , i am a new guy in jsf.

Comment: where you want to show toolTip on your jsp page.

Comment: i want to show tooltip on my output text.but output text did not bind a java bean.

Comment: use titile attribute in outputText component it shows an tootip message like 'DEFAULT TOOLTIP CONTENT' Ex: <h:outputText title="DEFAULT TOOLTIP CONTENT"></h:outputText>

Comment: can you desc it in detail?

Comment: In jsf some components have title attribute for displaying tooltip message. When the cursor is moving on those components the tool tip is displayed if that component mention 'title' attribute. You asked how to set tooltip value using javascript.. you don't need rich:toolTip component for displaying toolTip message. Simply use h:outputText and mention attribute title write the message what you want to display as a tooltip.